# Ubuntu autopilot install guide missing steps

Tags: vmware, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have downloaded the VMware image for the Ubuntu autopilot and trying to follow [the install guide on this site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive)

problem is, after step 5, there is nothing to show any openstack installation instructions/links/etc..
I end up after step 5 with a working MAAS site with three VMs in the ready state.

what should I do next to "see" the screens and options shown in step 6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the question. After completing step 4 of [OpenStack Autopilot Test Drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive), the `autopilot-config` script will also print out a large message banner on the command line which will direct the user to the URL where Landscape (the Autopilot) is running and the credentials you need to login and see the cloud installer.

Alternatively, if you missed that message on the console when you last ran autopilot-config you can still dig up those details for the Landscape URL and credentials cached in `/home/ubuntu/deployer.cfg` file.

The file is YAML, and you will want to point your browser to the IP specified at maas-server:ipaddress. The credentials for your install are in the `openstack-services` section as `admin-email` and `admin-password`.

If you want a script to report the 3 items out of YAML, here is an ugly one-liner that you run on the command line where your deployer.cfg lives. It will extract the URL for the autopilot UI and credentials from the YAML.

`python -c 'import yaml; cfg=yaml.load(open("deployer.cfg")); print "https://{} Credentials: {} / {}".format(cfg["maas-server"]["ipaddress"], cfg["openstack-services"]["admin-email"], cfg["openstack-services"]["admin-password"])'`